# Guardar datos en 2 tablas mysql / php

Tags: php, mysql

¿Como se puede hacer para guardar los datos en 2 tablas diferentes?

En una tabla *(usuarios)* tengo el *id_usuario, nomyape, email, telefono, id_categoria y activo*.

En otra tabla *(usuarioesc)* tengo el *id_usuario, id_escuela y password*.

Puse 2 INSERT INTO para las 2 tablas pero salta este error:

> Notice: Undefined index: password in
> C:............\usuarios.php on line 24 You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO
> usuarioesc ( id_escuela, password ) VALUE ( '1', '')' at line 2

Dice que no identifica password pero está bien escrito y que después no identifica el segundo INSERT INTO.

```
function agregarUsuario ()
{
    $link = conectar();
    $nomyape = $_POST ['nomyape'];
    $email = $_POST ['email'];
    $telefono = $_POST ['telefono'];
    $id_categoria = $_POST ['id_categoria'];
    $activo = $_POST ['activo'];
    $password = $_POST ['password'];
    $id_escuela = $_POST ['id_escuela'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios ( nomyape, email, telefono, id_categoria, activo ) VALUE ( '".$nomyape."', '".$email."', '".$telefono."', '".$id_categoria."', 1 )
            INSERT INTO usuarioesc ( id_escuela, password ) VALUE ( '".$id_escuela."', '".$password."')";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($link, $sql)
    or die( mysqli_error($link) );
    return $resultado;
}
```

**OPCIÓN 2:**

También intente de agregarlos separados, así:

```
function agregarUsuario ()
{
    $link = conectar();
    $nomyape = $_POST ['nomyape'];
    $email = $_POST ['email'];
    $telefono = $_POST ['telefono'];
    $id_categoria = $_POST ['id_categoria'];
    $activo = $_POST ['activo'];
    $password = pass ($_POST ['password']);
    $id_escuela = $_POST ['id_escuela'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios ( nomyape, email, telefono, id_categoria, activo ) VALUE ( '".$nomyape."', '".$email."', '".$telefono."', '".$id_categoria."', 1 )";
    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO usuarioesc ( id_escuela, password ) VALUE ( '".$id_escuela."', '".$password."')";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($link, $sql)
    $resultado2 = mysqli_query($link, $sql2)
    or die( mysqli_error($link) );
    return $resultado, $resultado2;
}
```

Pero dice el siguiente error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$resultado2' (T_VARIABLE) in ...

Dejo aca el formulario:

```
Nombre y apellido:<br>
<input type="text" name="nomyape" required><br>

Contraseña:<br>
<input type="password" id="password" >
<i id="pass-status" class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true" onClick="viewPassword()"></i>
<br>

Email:<br>
<input type="email" name="email" required><br>

Teléfono:<br>
<input type="tel" name="telefono" required><br>

Escuela:<br>
<input type="text" name="id_escuela" required><br>

Categoría:<br>
<input type="number" name="id_categoria" required><br>

Estado:<br>
<input type="number" name="activo" required><br>

<button class="btn-dark btn-block">Agregar</button>
```

Nueva edición, aplique los siguientes cambios en el código, pero ahora salta

> Notice: Array to string conversion in...

```
function agregarUsuario ()
{
    $link = conectar();
    $nomyape = $_POST ['nomyape'];
    $email = $_POST ['email'];
    $telefono = $_POST ['telefono'];
    $id_categoria = $_POST ['id_categoria'];
    $activo = $_POST ['activo'];
    $password = array('password');
    $id_escuela = $_POST ['id_escuela'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios ( nomyape, email, telefono, id_categoria, activo ) VALUE ( '".$nomyape."', '".$email."', '".$telefono."', '".$id_categoria."', 1 )";
    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO usuarioesc ( id_escuela, password ) VALUE ( '".$id_escuela."', '".$password."')";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($link, $sql)  or die( mysqli_error($link) );
    $resultado2 = mysqli_query($link, $sql2) or die( mysqli_error($link) );
    return [$resultado, $resultado2];
}
```

Y en la tabla publica ARRAY

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ambos al final tienen el cierre de `";` .

Comment: Pero como dice BetaM, son 2 consultas independientes, deben tener sus propias secuencias. En la opcion 2, estás ejecutando el $resultado 1 y 2, pero el 1 no lo estás cerrando. Por eso el error.

Comment: lo correcto siempre es usar transacciones siempre que se afecten mas de una tabla al mismo tiempo.

Comment: La sintaxis está mal. Es `INSERT INTO... VALUES(...)`. Tienes VALUE

Comment: Ahi lo modifique, pero ahora el problema es que no identifica la contraseña. En cambio pone en la tabla la palabra Array y el error dice: `Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\...\usuarios.php on line 27` que la linea 27 es esta: `$sql2 = "INSERT INTO usuarioesc ( id_escuela, password ) VALUES ( '".$id_escuela."', '".$password."')";`

Comment: Quita el `$password = array('password');` y ponlo como antes `$password = $_POST ['password'];`

Comment: `Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\...\usuarios.php on line 24` que es `$password = $_POST ['password'];` .Será por que le tengo que decir que password esta en otra tabla? Este esta en usuarioesc. Debe ser que esta buscando en la otra tabla (usuarios). Como le digo que password esta en usuarioesc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que quieres ejecutar 2 secuencias en una sola con lo siguiente:

```
$resultado = mysqli_query($link, $sql) $resultado2 = mysqli_query($link, $sql2) or die( mysqli_error($link) );
return $resultado, $resultado2;
```

Solo dividelo para que se ejecute independientemente, asi:

```
$resultado = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
$resultado2 = mysqli_query($link, $sql2));

if ($resultado && $resultado2){
  return "Insertado!";
}else {
  return mysqli_error($link);
}
```

Resultado final:

```
function agregarUsuario ()
{
    $link= conectar();
    $nomyape = $_POST ['nomyape'];
    $email = $_POST ['email'];
    $telefono = $_POST ['telefono'];
    $id_categoria = $_POST ['id_categoria'];
    $activo = $_POST ['activo'];
    $password = $_POST ['password'];
    $id_escuela = $_POST ['id_escuela'];
    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO usuarios ( nomyape, email, telefono, id_categoria, activo ) VALUES ( '".$nomyape."', '".$email."', '".$telefono."', '".$id_categoria."', 1 )";
    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO usuarioesc ( id_escuela, password ) VALUES ( '".$id_escuela."', '".$password."')";
    
    $resultado1 = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    $resultado2 = mysqli_query($link, $sql2);
    
    if ($resultado1 && $resultado2){
      return "Insertado!";
    }else {
      return mysqli_error($link);
    }
}
```

Comment: De esta forma tira error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ';' in` La forma que pudo hacer para continuar sin error fue asi `return $resultado; return $resultado2;`

Comment: Ahi lo modifique de la siguiente manera `return $resultado; return $resultado2;` pero dice `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function pass() in C:\...\usuarios.php:24 Stack trace: #0 C:\....\agregarUsuario.php(7): agregarUsuario() #1 {main} thrown in` así que me decise del pass() y ahora no identifica la contraseña.( `Undefined index: password ` )

Comment: Ponlo dentro de un array para obtener los valores

Comment: ¿Dónde pongo el array? Al final de todo? Lo puse así `array (pass =>$password );` junto con la password de la siguiente manera `$password = pass($_POST ['password']);` pero sigue diciendo `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function pass()` que no se que quiere decir o por que no lo toma

Comment: En el return `return [$resultado, $resultado2];`, lo edite

Comment: Si, ahi lo cambie  a `return [$resultado, $resultado2];` pero sigue sin identificar la password o pass()

Comment: Ahi realice cambios en la pregunta

Comment: Ahi lo edite, deberia funcionarte @Cloby

Comment: Muchas gracias Juan! Pero salta el siguiente error: `Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\...\usuarios.php on line 27` que la linea 27 es esta: `$sql2 = "INSERT INTO usuarioesc ( id_escuela, password ) VALUE ( '".$id_escuela."', '".$password."')";`